# Pass Through Query With Parameters

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013, pass-through

I am attempting to run a `Access 2013` pass through query that takes two parameters from my VBA syntax.  When I run this, I get a compile error of

> expected end of statement
>   " and "

How should this sub be modified in order for this to be valid sql string?

```
Public Sub GeneratePassThroughForJob()

    Dim qdfPassThrough As DAO.QueryDef, MyDB As Database
    Dim strConnect As String, d1 As String, d2 As String, Dim SQL As String

    d1 = Format(Forms!DataPull!txtd1, "YYYY-MM-DD")
    d2 = Format(Forms!DataPull!txtd2, "YYYY-MM-DD")

    If Not IsNull(CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qrySQLPass").SQL) Then
        CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete "qrySQLPass"
    End If

    Set MyDB = CurrentDb()
    Set qdfPassThrough = MyDB.CreateQueryDef("qrySQLPass")
    strConnect = "ValidSQLServerConnectionString"

    qdfPassThrough.Connect = "ODBC;" & strConnect

    SQL = "Select fname, lname, address from einfo where startdate between "&d1&" and "&d2&""

    qdfPassThrough.SQL = "Select fname, lname, address from einfo where startdate between "&d1&" and "&d2&""

    qdfPassThrough.ReturnsRecords = False
    qdfPassThrough.Close

    Application.RefreshDatabaseWindow

    DoCmd.OpenQuery "qrySQLPass", acViewNormal, acReadOnly
    DoCmd.Maximize
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try printing that sql in the immediate window?

Comment: How can I print it when the error is thrown as soon as I move the cursor to a new line?

Comment: How about you define the sql as a string before anything else?

Comment: I added the sql as a string, but again as soon as I move the cursor it throws the error.

Comment: Go to the immediate window and type `?"Select fname, lname, address from einfo where startdate between "&d1&" and "&d2&""`

Comment: You have a funny number of quotes and you woud be best off using a proper parameter query.

Comment: Immediat window returns - Select fname, lname, address from einfo where startdate between 0 and 0

Comment: BTW Why passthrough rather than linked, which MS recommends?

Comment: The query is using multiple CTE and the Row_Number() function -> And I have been unable to replicate the query in access, so I was going to try to use a parameter pass through query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138229/discussion-between-fionnuala-and-michael-mormon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dates should be quoted for SQL Server, and don't forget the spaces:

```
SQL = "Select fname, lname, address from einfo where startdate between '" & d1 & "' and '" & d2 & "'"
```